# Retrieve Blogger post URL

Tags: php, xml, blogger

I'm trying to retrieve posts from a Blogger using PHP and XML:

```
$file="BLOG URL/atom.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

And making a simple loop:

```
foreach ($xml->entry as $foo) {
    echo '<h2>' . $foo->title . '</h2>';
    echo '<p>' . $foo->updated . '</p>';
    echo $foo->link;
}
```

The only problem is that link is not showed.

Inspecting the code, each post has more than one link node:

```
<link href="" rel="replies" title="Postar comentários" type="application/atom+xml"/>
<link href="" rel="replies" title="0 Comentários" type="text/html"/>
<link href="" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"/>
<link href="" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
<link href="" rel="alternate" title="" type="text/html"/>
```

Is possible to get a node by his type atributte?

Comment: Get a node by WHAT type of attribute? Are you only trying to get one of those link values?

Comment: You might read this documentation https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?csw=1#RetrievingEntries

Comment: Or this if you are using API 3.0 https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingPostsForABlog

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. The $foo variable at that node as multiple links, so you can't tell it which you want to output when you output $foo->link.

Comment: @MikelBitson Yes. This is exactly my problem. Is thare a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by looping through the links and selecting one. So change:

```
foreach ($xml->entry as $foo) {
    echo '<h2>' . $foo->title . '</h2>';
    echo '<p>' . $foo->updated . '</p>';
    echo $foo->link;
}
```

To:

```
foreach ( $xml->entry as $foo ) {
    echo '<h2>' . $foo->title . '</h2>';
    echo '<p>' . $foo->updated . '</p>';
    foreach ( $foo->link as $link ) {
        $type = (string) $link->attributes()->{'type'};
        if ( $type == 'text/html' ) {
            echo (string) $link->attributes()->{'title'};;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `'text/html'` is the type you want to select.

Comment: @marcelo2605 Updated the answer with working code using the URL you provided. Example of my output: http://devimg.next-www.com/20151112191811441.png